# Authentication token expiry in Expo

Tags: reactjs, authentication, expo

I am trying to implement authentication in my first expo project and I am kinda struggling with token expiration.

This is my auth context:

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext({
  token: "",
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authenticate: (token) => {},
  logout: () => {},
});

const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState();

  const authenticate = (token) => {
    setAuthToken(token);
    AsyncStorage.setItem("token", token);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setAuthToken(null);
    AsyncStorage.removeItem("token");
  };

  const value = {
    token: authToken,
    isAuthenticated: !!authToken,
    authenticate: authenticate,
    logout: logout,
  };

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export default AuthContextProvider;
```

This is my index.js file where I structure my axios calls (/src/api/index.js):

```
import axios from "axios";
import { API_BASE_URL } from "@env";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

let getApiBaseURL = API_BASE_URL || "http://localhost:3000/api/v1";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: getApiBaseURL,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});

api.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");

    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }

    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export const exampleFetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await api.get(`${API_BASE_URL}/employees`);

    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }
};
```

The problem is:

I want to use interceptor to check whether my token is valid or not. If its not valid then trigger logout. I don't want to use intervals/timeouts to check token validity but rather trigger it when user wants an API call. The issue is that I can't use context functions outside of functional components' bodies.

How can I achieve this? I want to call logout inside interceptor.

I solved it adding setTimeout but thats not something I want